# Minimize to tray with SWT

Tags: java, swt, system-tray, minimize

I'm trying to make a SWT-app that I'm building to minimize itself to it's tray-icon (i.e. a TrayItem in SWT). More specifically I want to achieve the following:

- Both pressing close and minimize will minimize the app.
- The app is not shown in the task-bar while it's minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [intercept](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Changethedefaultbehaviorofshells.htm) window events in SWT quite easily.

Hiding apps from taskbar is something I haven't tried and I'd assume it requires calling some native function. I've found an example with taskbar which may be a starting point [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet336.java) .

Comment: `shell.setVisible()` should be sufficient to hide a window.